# How to change the string in onDownloadStart?

Tags: android

How to replace "+" signs with "_" and "/" signs with "=" in the file names before my download manager downloads the file?

```
@Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimeType,
                                    long contentLength) {
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                    Uri.parse(url));
            request.setMimeType(mimeType);
            String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
            request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
            request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
            request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
            request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition,
                    mimeType));
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(
                            url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: Asking the same question twice is not going to give you a different answer. I already answered your question. I tested it and it worked. Then you deleted the question....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume that your string/filename is:

```
String myFileName = "basal_metabolic_rate+example.pdf";
```

You can replace the `+` with `_` by doing the following:

```
String result = myFileName.replaceAll("[+]", "_");
```

The string `result` will now return:

`basal_metabolic_rate_example.pdf`

---

Same goes for when you want to replace "/" with "=" , then you can do:

```
String myFileName = "basal/metabolic/rate/example.pdf";
String result = myFileName.replaceAll("[/]", "=");

// Your file will now be basal=metabolic=rate=example.pdf
```

---

**EDIT:**

Here is how you can implement it in your code:

```
@Override
public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimeType, long contentLength) {

        //You can first get the filename:
        String filename = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType);
        //Then you can replace the "+" with "_"
        String replacePlus = filename.replaceAll("[+]", "_");
        //Then you can replace the "/" with "="
        String replaceSlash = replacePlus.replaceAll("[/]", "=");

        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
        Uri.parse(url));
        request.setMimeType(mimeType);
        String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
        request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
        request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
        request.setDescription("Downloading file...");

        //Now here where you set the title you can set it to the last edited string, like this:
        request.setTitle(replaceSlash);

        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

        //And here where you set the destination directory
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, replaceSlash);

        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        dm.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: man how do I implement this in my code? IT gives me errors. Have you really "tested" it??

Comment: Yes I have tested it and it works. Where did you implement this and what errors did it give you?

Comment: Please see my edit, this is how I would implement it. I have also added comments.